# run bash script in PowerShell with ssh fails with invalid format

Tags: bash, powershell, ssh

I created a simple bash script that runs fine on Ubuntu 18/20.
Decided to port it onto PowerShell.
I start PowerShell in Windows 10.
Then type: ssh 192.168.1.56
This allows me to reach the target.
(the key is located in /c/users/joe90/.ssh/)

On the other hand, the bash script does the same thing:

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh 192.168.1.56
```

Yet, I keep getting this error:
load pubkey "/c/Users/joe90/.ssh/mykey-xyz": invalid format

The only thing I was able to sort out is that typing from PowerShell:
ssh -V
return ==> OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5

But when the myBash.sh bash script runs (/usr/bin/bash ...):
ssh -V
return --> OpenSSH_8.3p1 ...

Any thoughts ?

**Additional Notes:
The answer seems to lie [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=256210). It does ssh onto target but always leave this error mentioned. I tried to make a public key with no success.**

Comment: Do you have a key in `/c/Users/joe90/.ssh/` ? Is the format supported by the windows build ? Some `ssh` clients try and load keys automatically. Editing the client's configuration might help to prevent this from happening and failing.

Comment: I do have a key in .ssh. 
ssh from PowerShell and command line works fine.
The problem is when I run the bash script inside PowerShell, I get this error. The best answer I read until now is that /usr/bin/ssh uses OpenSsh 8.3 which is more restrictive. But what ?

Comment: my batch file started git bash not bash. This is where the problem was. Technically, I should remove git bash and install Ubuntu for Windows package

Comment: Installed an older version of git bash. 2.24. No more errors.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
/usr/bin/ssh 192.168.1.56
```

instead (assuming this is the one you want to run).

Verify it using

```
/usr/bin/ssh -V
```

form `bash`, or

```
sh -c '/usr/bin/ssh -V'
```

from `powershell`.

Comment: Thx, but none of this help. I am not sure you understand my question

Answer (score 0):

Any time I see "invalid format" while using Windows Subsystem for Linux, I run dos2unix on that file and that seems to clear up a lot of errors. In WSL you just type: dos2unix fileName.txt